# Is ASP.NET not developed for the web?

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp

I think this question looks silly and I don't agree with the subject.

Someone who I know by sight mentioned in his comment that ASP.NET and JSP are not developed for the web, and PHP is the best language for the web.

However, I can't understand his idea on this because ASP.NET and JSP are developed for the web. If it's not, then why do they use the name? (i.e. 'Server Page')

Do you have any ideas about that?

Why did he mention that kind of idea?

Are there any grounds?

Comment: "who I know by sight" like i know the pope?

Comment: Just so you know, this question was closed because it is very discursive, and as such has no single correct answer. Have a read of the FAQ when you get a moment `:)`.

Comment: Thanks halfer for your information. The problem is that I cannot use my account anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He probably means that Java and C# (which are the programming languages usually used with JSP and ASP.NET) were not developed primarily for the web.

That doesn't, in the least little bit, make them less suitable than PHP for server side web development.

Answer (score 2):

They are wrong.  Of course it is for the web.
From wikipedia:

> ASP.NET is a server-side Web application framework designed for Web
>   development to produce dynamic Web pages. It was developed by
>   Microsoft to allow programmers to build dynamic web sites, web
>   applications and web services. It was first released in January 2002
>   with version 1.0 of the .NET Framework, and is the successor to
>   Microsoft's Active Server Pages (ASP) technology. ASP.NET is built on
>   the Common Language Runtime (CLR), allowing programmers to write
>   ASP.NET code using any supported .NET language. The ASP.NET SOAP
>   extension framework allows ASP.NET components to process SOAP
>   messages.